# Access base member in a class, which derives from a nested class in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, inner-classes

I would like to have a template, which has nested class. Then I would like to have a template, which inherits the first template and also has a nested class. Then I would like this nested class to inherit his owner base nested class. I can do it, but I can't access members of the first nested class from another. What am I doing wrong, or is it impossible at all? Why? What have I do to fix the problem (if possible)/alternative decision (if impossible)?

```
template <class T, class T2>
class Class1
{
public:
    class NestedClass1;
};

template <class T, class T2>
class Class1<T, T2>::NestedClass1
{
public:
    void Do()
    {

    }
};

template <class T>
class Class2 : Class1<T, int>
{
public:
    class NestedClass2;
};

template <class T>
class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::NestedClass1
{
public:
    void Do2()
    {
        this->Do(); // Why there is no "Do" in this?
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried to compile your example and got the following error:
`circular inheritance between 'Class2<T>::NestedClass2' and 'Class2::NestedClass2'`
Your problem can be solved by defining `NestedClass2` as:
`class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class1<T, int>::NestedClass1`

I don't know what exactly goes wrong in your example but I think it has something to do with using `Class2` on both sides of `:` i.e. in the base and in the child part.

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/6W6h8G64e).

Comment: @mix which compiler produces this error?

Comment: Clang see: [https://godbolt.org/z/c6Trc593h](https://godbolt.org/z/c6Trc593h)

Comment: It looks Clang requires you to write things like these: `class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::template Class1<T,int>::NestedClass1`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K8Wsraoah)

Comment: This seems to work as well: `class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::Class1::NestedClass1`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jYsdefeTz)

Comment: I can use any:

`class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::NestedClass1`
`class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::template Class1<T, int>::NestedClass1`
`class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::template Class1<T,int>::NestedClass1`
`class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::Class1::NestedClass1`

There is no differene for my compilier for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

That code of yours seems like it does not compile equally well on popular compilers:

```
template <class T>
class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::NestedClass1
```

About it clang complains that `Class2` does not have any `NestedClass1` in it.
It technically has, as inherited nested class is nested class too, however clang disagrees in said context and so do tools that are built using clang's codebase.

Here is workaround that works on all three major compilers:

```
template <class T>
class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class1<T, int>::NestedClass1
```

Comment: Class2 absolutely has NestedClass1 in it, inherited from Class1.

Comment: gcc says it has clang says it has not. Both seem content with my suggestion.

Comment: I can also use `class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class1<T, int>::NestedClass1`. It is the same as mine `class Class2<T>::NestedClass2 final : Class2<T>::NestedClass1` for IDE.

Comment: That kind of controversies can happen when Visual Studio uses msvc as compiler but clang's parts in code analysis. Try to write code that all 3 compilers handle same way. Code, that the clever tools can't read is guaranteed to be confusing for human reader too.